# Pandas - Strip col1 values from column2 values if exists match (regex match with dynamic value)

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a task to update values in column_1 IF it has a full match to value from column_2.
Like so

```
name              city
Danny London      London
Tim Detroit       Detroit
Keith New Orleans The city of New Orleans
Mary Jane         London
```

=>

```
name              city
Danny             London                   <- updated
Tim               Detroit                  <- updated
Keith New Orleans The city of New Orleans  
Mary Jane         London
```

So far I've tried this

```
condlidt = [df.apply(lambda x: x.name_cleaned.endwith(f"{x.city}"), axis=1)]
choicelist = [df.name_cleaned.str.replace(rf'{df.city}$', '', regex=True]
fd['name_cleaned'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=df.name_cleaned)
```

But it returns the same df. I've checked and `condlist` works as expected - returns True/False for values, the problem is in `choicelist` - not sure how to pass regex with dynamic value. Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead test by `endswith` you can add value `$` for end of string and also `\s+` for match spaces and repalce these values to empty string in `re.sub`:

```
import re

df['name'] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub(rf"\s+{x.city}$",'',x['name']), axis=1)
print (df)
                name                     city
0              Danny                   London
1                Tim                  Detroit
2  Keith New Orleans  The city of New Orleans
3          Mary Jane                   London
```